# Peanut Butter Chocolate Stout- Cocoa or Nibs?

Tags: recipe, stout

I'm looking to piece together a Peanut Butter Chocolate Stout recipe and I torn between using powdered cocoa late in the boil or cocoa nibs in secondary. Any suggestions?

Also, with either suggestion, how much do you suggest using for a moderate amount of chocolate flavor?

Answer (score 1):

I just brewed this! I used this recipe which has a lot of great discussion. I used cocoa powder & peanut butter powder in the secondary, and added cocoa nibs a week later (sanitized by soaking in as little vodka as possible overnight).

http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f12/chocolate-covered-beavr-nutz-362380/

This recipe is amazing, I'll be making it again even without cocoa or peanut butter it is a great stout recipe.

Comment: I agree do both. I have added cocoa nibs to the boil as well. Added them 10 minutes to the end of the boil and got great flavor that way.

Comment: @andrhamm Thanks for the links and suggestions. I'm leaning towards using a little of both after your suggestions and further research. Ever tasted Southern Tier Chocolate Stout? Talk about chocolate-y goodness!

Comment: Southern Tier Choklat- BA Review             http://beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/3818/40058

Comment: @TravisWood I haven't but I definitely will, maybe as commercial calibration when I'm taste testing mine

Answer (score 0):

I've used 250g cocoa powder in 25L of Robust Porter a number of times (both at flameout and added after primary), and it comes out tasting very dark-chocolatey. I haven't used nibs before, so I can't give you a comparison.

I'd be very interested to hear how you plan to get the peanut butter flavour - I've considered making a similar beer, but have been put off by the problems associated with using actual peanut butter.

Comment: Most of research I have done so far into this recipe has led me to powdered peanut butter: PB2  http://www.amazon.com/PB2-Powdered-Peanut-Butter-6-5/dp/B002GJ9JWS   It sounds like this is the solution to a fatty/oily PB that will just clog up fermentation.

Comment: Thanks, I've not seen or heard of powdered peanut butter before - I'll have to keep an eye out for it!

Comment: Yes the PB2 is fantastic, I ordered two chocolate & pb ones and one PB one from amazon (only used the PB one so far but planning to use the chocolate ones in a later batch). I added enough water to pour and boiled for a short while, then cooled and added to secondary. Chime in on that forum with your results!